# Show Parameters for Reports In SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I'm developing an SSRS in Visual Studio BIDS. In it, I have a link that links to another report (report A). Report A has 4 parameters (dates). When I click on that link, it goes to report A fine, but the 4 parameters in report A are hidden (I would have to click on the arrows to show them and edit them).

How can I make the link link to report A with parameters unhidden by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Instead of using drillthrough reports you can use the jump to URL feature and call the report explicity. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx) details the URL access parameters and [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bilive/archive/2009/02/19/hyperlink-in-a-new-window-in-reporting-services-report.aspx) one shows how to setup the URL to open in a new window.