# How to display full URL when setting report parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, query-string

I have a report (in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008) that has multiple parameters, but works very well.  However, one of my users (my boss, of course) wants to be able to e-mail a link to the report using the parameters they have specified.  They do not want to send the report itself, but just a link to it.  However, as you set parameter values and click "View Report", the URL shown in the browser does not contain the parameter values in the querystring (just the default report path), and therefore is not really usable.

I know that this functionality is possible, because if I add a subscription to the report, and check the "include link" checkbox, I get an e-mail with a link like this:

http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fRoot+Action+Analysis&ShowChart=2&sPN=&iDept=All&rs%3aParameterLanguage=en-US

Is there a server setting that could be changed to show the FULL URL (with parameters) as users generate new reports?
Thank in advance!

Comment: You're missing a slightly important point in your question: what's the report server you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I jumped right into this.  This is SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS 2008).  I have been reading so many posts, I forgot to be more specific.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: dup? : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1743841/144496

Comment: No, this is not really a duplicate question/post. The other thread mentions two posts: One lists parameters that can be passed when going to sub-reports or links within reports. The other shows methods for handling links within reports.  My report is a single report (no subreports or drill-downs) and the user does not click on links within the report (only the "View Report" button I mentioned earlier).   Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to change the settings so that the full URL is shown.

As a workaround you could add a textbox to the bottom of your report, and build the URL yourself in an expression by concatenating Globals!ReportServerURL, Globals!ReportFolder, Globals!ReportName, Globals!Language and your various Parameters.

Comment: Fillet - Your suggestion work great!  Thanks for the idea and guidance.

Comment: Take a look at the following links about passing parameters via the URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx and http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1336 once you know how the URL's for SSRS work, you can send personalized emails to different people with their own URL and Parameter settings.